# Reset Logic in Chisel

Tags: chisel

How to assign the explicit reset to a register. When RegInit() is used, global reset signal assign to it . However if you want to drive the reset signal through custom logic in a module then how  can we avoid implicit reset.
for example

```
... 
state_reg = RegInit(st_reset)

when( reset_i) {
state_reg:= st_reset
}.elsewhen(error_s) {
state_reg := st_error
}.otherwise     {
state_reg:= next_state_reg_s
}
 ....
```

Can anyone explain how to control reset logic.

Comment: @ My approach drive from vhdl based fsm.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the register in the scope of another clock.  Something like

```
val reg2 = withClock(clock2) { RegInit(0.U(8.W)) }
```

See the following [chisel3 tests multiclock example](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/master/src/test/scala/chiselTests/MultiClockSpec.scala) for the full implementation.